# Moshi: Parse NULL value which suppose to be an integer

Tags: java, moshi

I have a class like

```
public class Data{
   int integer_value = 0;
}
```

Then I got json from server `{"integer_value":null}`

When I trying to parse it by

```
String json = "{\"integer_value\":null}"
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
JsonAdapter<Data> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Data.class);
Data data = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
```

It will throw exception:

```
Caused by: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected an int but was NULL at path $.integer_value
```

How can I prevent this? I would like it as if "integer_value" is absent. Therefore it would use the default value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: (imports omitted)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"integer_value\":null}";
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new ZeroWhenNullAdapter()).build();
        JsonAdapter<Data> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Data.class);
        Data data = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Nullable { // you can use any annotation named 'Nullable'
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
public @interface ZeroWhenNull {}

public class Data {
    @ZeroWhenNull
    int integer_value = 0;
}

public class ZeroWhenNullAdapter {
    // this isn't really needed, but Moshi insists that adapters work both
    // ways as far as I can tell
    @ToJson
    String toJson(@ZeroWhenNull int n) {
        return Integer.toString(n);
    }

    @FromJson
    @ZeroWhenNull
    int fromJson(@Nullable String n) {
        return n == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(n);
    }
}
```

This *isn't* using the default, it is explicitly setting the field to zero.